# I am doing a simple Oracle INSERT and I keep getting this error: [Err] ORA-00984: column not allowed here

Tags: function, plsql, package

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kpupd.png)

```
FUNCTION insert_in_sales(
    sale_id NUMBER,
    prod_id NUMBER,
    customer_id NUMBER,
    quantity NUMBER,
    sale_date DATE
) RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO sales(SaleID, ProductID, CustomerID, Quantity, SaleDate)
VALUES(sale_id, prod_id, cust_id, quantity, sale_date);
COMMIT;
RETURN 'New sales record added successfully';
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
    ROLLBACK;
RETURN 'An error occurred ' || SQLERRM;
END insert_in_sales;
```

the error as much as i think is bcoz some of the parameters from the parameter list in the insert and values function dont match their datatypes.
Do correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: The name of one of your values is different than the name of the parameter. Try changing "cust_id" to "customer_id" in the INSERT statement.

Answer (score 1):

The values in the insert statement need to match the values in the insert statement (argument is customer_id and insert statement references cust_id). That is the root cause of this error. However, in general it is better to use a prefix for the function arguments so it is clear in your code what strings are column names and what strings are variables. In the function you posted, the argument is "quantity" and the table also has a column "quantity". In an insert statement this should be ok, but for an update statement this could lead to unexpected behaviour (update column to column vs update column to argument).
using a prefix will also make your code more readable/maintainable/understandable.

```
oracle 19c >CREATE TABLE sales (
  2     saleid     NUMBER
  3        CONSTRAINT sales_pk PRIMARY KEY
  4     ,productid  NUMBER
  5     ,customerid NUMBER
  6     ,quantity   NUMBER
  7     ,saledate   DATE
  8* );

Table SALES created.

oracle 19c >CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_in_sales(
  2      p_sale_id NUMBER,
  3      p_prod_id NUMBER,
  4      p_customer_id NUMBER,
  5      p_quantity NUMBER,
  6      p_sale_date DATE
  7  ) RETURN VARCHAR2
  8  IS
  9  BEGIN
 10  INSERT INTO sales(saleid, productid, customerid, quantity, saledate)
 11      VALUES(p_sale_id, p_prod_id, p_customer_id, p_quantity, p_sale_date);
 12  COMMIT;
 13  RETURN 'New sales record added successfully';
 14  EXCEPTION
 15  WHEN OTHERS THEN
 16      ROLLBACK;
 17  RETURN 'An error occurred ' || SQLERRM;
 18  END insert_in_sales;
 19* /

Function INSERT_IN_SALES compiled

oracle 19c >
```